# Font awesome doesn't work in ReactJS for custom variable

Tags: reactjs, image, font-awesome

I am working in the reactJS single page application project. In that I am surprised with font awesome is not working. Really I am not sure why this part is not working. Here is my code

```
.profileImage {
    position: relative;
    &:after{
        content:'\f107';
        position: absolute;
        right: -10px;
        top: 50%;
        transform: translateY(-50%);
        width: 10px;
        height: 10px;
        font-size: 12px;
        font-family: $fa-font-path;
    }
}
```

**$fa-font-path;** which is a custom variable.

Comment: This has nothing do to with react at all. If it's not working you have some other issue, FA should work as in every other environment.

Comment: did you installed font-awesome?

Comment: @ShubhamRaj nope but i have font awesome css

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use FA in css, make sure you installed FA

```
npm install --save font-awesome
```

and added

```
import 'font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css
```

in your `index.tsx`

Comment: Sorry, but isnt font-family supposed to be "font-family: FontAwesome;" and $fa-font-path to have a path to FA files folder (like "$fa-font-path: "/fonts" !default;")?

Comment: i haven't dowloaded its font

Comment: Ehm... ok? You mean you added cdn or what?